# jQuery dynamically add selected value with its parent data like formatted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my html code looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="shortcode_selected_package" name="shortcode_selected_package">

    <div class="selected-packages-wrap">
      <div class="shortcode-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="data-remove" data-id="220" data-name="New custom pack">-</a><label>New custom pack</label>
        <span class="package-cats">
                    <span><input class="package-cat" data-parent="220" value="5" type="checkbox">10 GB</span>
        <span><input class="package-cat" data-parent="220" value="6" type="checkbox">6 GB</span>
        <span><input class="package-cat" data-parent="220" value="26" type="checkbox">Sony</span>
        <span><input class="package-cat" data-parent="220" value="25" type="checkbox">Unlimited Calls</span></span>
      </div>

      <div class="shortcode-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="data-remove" data-id="417" data-name="Test New Packs">-</a><label>Test New Packs</label>
        <span class="package-cats">
                    <span><input class="package-cat" data-parent="417" value="5" type="checkbox">10 GB</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="shortcode-wrap">
        <a class="data-remove" href="#" data-id="219" data-cat-id="7|6|24" data-cat-name="12 - 20 GB|6 GB|Unlimited Messages" data-name="Test package">-</a><label>Test package</label>
        <span class="package-cats">
                    <span><input class="package-cat" type="checkbox" data-parent="219" value="7">12 - 20 GB</span>
        <span><input class="package-cat" type="checkbox" data-parent="219" value="6">6 GB</span>
        <span><input class="package-cat" type="checkbox" data-parent="219" value="24">Unlimited Messages</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In my code when someone checks the 10 GB, Unlimited Calls checkbox for the first div then the value should be assigned to the `shortcode`_selected_package div. So let's say someone if checks to the first element of the top div which is `data-id="220"` then the value should be assigned to the div is like

```
220[5|6]
```

again when someone clicks to the 10 GB of the second div then the value should be like

```
220[5|6],417[5]
```

In the same if someone checks to the Unlimited Messages of the last div then the value should be like this

```
220[5|6],417[5],219[24]
```

If someone unchecks the checkbox then the respective value should be remove as well from the value

So can someone tell me how to do this.

In the following code is always showing only one single data. Not updating the older one which was checked.

```
$('div.selected-packages-wrap').find('input.package-cat').change(function() {
      var Parent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
      var Selected = $(this).val();
      var SelectedPackages = $('#shortcode_selected_package').val();
      if (SelectedPackages !== '' || SelectedPackages !== undefined) {
        tmp = SelectedPackages.split(',');

        var index = tmp.indexOf(Parent);

        if (index !== -1) {
          tmp.splice(index, 1);
          data = tmp.join('[' + Selected + '],');
          console.log(data);
        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you and you reverted... that is of course a waste of my time. Please in the future produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to start by thinking of how to structure your data, As I understood a user can select mutliple packages from different categories so you might have something like this

```
{
  [categoryId]: Array<PackageId>,
}
```

for example

```
{
  244: [100, 200],
  500: [6, 7]
}
```

Then you need to find a way to convert this data to this string format: `244[100|200],500[6|7]`, This is one way to do it

```
function formatPackages(data) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
      data[key] &&
      data[key].constructor === Array) {
      arr.push(key + '[' + data[key].join('|') + ']');
    }
  }
  return arr.join(',');
}
```

Now you need functions to **select** and **unselect** packages

```
var selectedPackages = {};

function selectPackage(parent, value) {
  if(selectedPackages[parent]) {
    selectedPackages[parent].push(value);
  } else {
    selectedPackages[parent] = [value];
  }
}

function unselectPackage(parent, value) {
  if(selectedPackages[parent]) {
    var index = selectedPackages[parent].indexOf(value);
    if(index > -1) {
      selectedPackages[parent].splice(index, 1);
    }
    if(selectedPackages[parent].length === 0) {
      delete selectedPackages[parent];
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have all the pieces together, you can add user handling

```
$('div.selected-packages-wrap').find('input.package-cat').change(function() {
  var parent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
  var value = $(this).val();

  if(this.checked) {
    selectPackage(parent, value);
  } else {
    unselectPackage(parent, value);
  }

$('#shortcode_selected_package').val(formatPackages(selectedPackages));
});
```

Here's a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bitriddler/eL9L8wxj/1/

Comment: Try the jsfiddle

Comment: I have used pipe | operator inside square bracket. Can you check that? please check my updated question

Comment: Okay great, Can you update the fiddle so that I can make this answer accepted.